# Can't ping EC2 instance through ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, ping

I'm trying to establish connection with a EC2 instance through ansible but it fails.

Here's the command:

```
ansible all -i hosts -u ec2-user -m ping
```

And the result I get:

```
44.256.222.13[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQ9JG.png)4 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: no such identity: /home/vagrant/key.perm: No such file or directory\r\nPermission denied (publickey).", 
    "unreachable": true
}
```

I have downloaded the `key.pem` file and I added it to the path in `ansible.cfg` as proposed.

Answer (score 1):

Check the permissions on the .pem:

```
chmod 400 /home/vagrant/key.perm
```

And, are you sure that the file is named .pe**r**m?

Comment: The file name is key.pem

Comment: The error message that you paste says that he can't find "key.perm"

Comment: Yes, i fixed that and also now i'm getting 44.235.185.144 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey).", 
    "unreachable": true
}

Comment: I copied the secret key from the downloaded key.pem and pasted it to the vm's key.pem file

Comment: Have you changed the permission on the file via chmod?

Comment: Yes, maybe the user name is not correct?

Comment: the default usernames for standard AMIs are here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html

Comment: Then it's weird, the vm is Ubuntu and i can't connect with 'ubuntu' user either

Comment: Maybe something went wrong in your copy and paste of the content of the key. Try to use the original file.